# Apply bootstrap arguments to heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

We assume that $u$ satisfies the heat equation $\partial_t u-\Delta u=f$ in some parabolic cylinder $Q_R=B_R\times(-R^2,0]$. What is the so-called **bootstrap arguments** to get the estimates of the following norms

$$||u||_{L^{\infty}(Q_{\frac{1}{2}R})}+||\nabla u||_{L^{\infty}(Q_{\frac{1}{2}R})}+||\nabla^2 u||_{L^{\infty}(Q_{\frac{1}{2}R})}+\sup_{-\frac{1}{4}R^2\leq t\leq 0}||\partial_t u(t)||_{L^{p}(B_{\frac{1}{2}R})}$$

by a constant relates to $f$ ?

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first energy estimate on the solution $u$ is obtained by taking the inner product in $L^2(B_r)$ and integrating over time the second which is on $\nabla u$ is obtained by using the fact that $\nabla u $ belongs to $L^2(-R^2,0; B_r)$ which is a consequence of the first energy estimate, namely you have also $\nabla u $ in $L^\infty (-R^2,0; B_r)$ if we start the evolution from $-R^2+ \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is any tiny positive real number and so on. The bootstraping method in general is based on iteration, namely you apply on your solution's derivatives with respect to space and time variables $ \nabla u$ and $\partial_t u$ what you applied on your solution $u$ and therefore you get estimates on them similar to those obtained on $u$.

Comment: This is realy interesting answer, can you support your answer by useful link please

Comment: You can see James C. Robinson's paper about the regularity problem of Navier Stokes equation the bootstrap method is detailed there

Comment: See this link http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/43977/